# what is the use Http GetMethod(String URI) constructor

Tags: java, apache

I have read the documnet regarding the GetMethod from the apache.org link 
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/tutorial.html, but i didn't get enough out of it. Could someone explain me whats the when should this method be used with a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetMethod(String URI) is used when you want to create HTTP GET request to the URI. The below example from the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/tutorial.html) explains everything.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

import java.io.*;

public class HttpClientTutorial {

  private static String url = "http://www.apache.org/";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an instance of HttpClient.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }  
  }
}
```

Please read the comments to understand clearly. Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please explain me these statements GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

Comment: method.getParams() returns the HttpProtocol parameters associated with this method in the form of HttpMethodParams Object. we are setting the property RETRY_HANDLER to the DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false)) with retryCount of 3 and requestSentRetryEnabled as false.

Comment: Just read the doc HttpMethodParams and DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMethod` actually implements the HTTP `GET` method. So if you want to send an HTTP `GET` request to some URL then you should use this.

Answer (score 0):

GetMethod accepts HTTP Get requests where the url is a query string as it is appears in the url,for example when u submit a form consists of userName and password and action on hitting login url the url appars as

http://[application-name]/login?userName=prawin&password=123

-its recommended to use post where you are sending a confidential info.
Thank you.